# Read only selected Packet SoftwareSerial

Tags: arduino-nano, softwareserial

I am reading data from RS485 which is in the following format:

```c
void sendkwh()
{
  RS485Serial.write((byte)0x01); // Meter Address
  RS485Serial.write((byte)0x03); // Read Function Code
  RS485Serial.write((byte)0x40); // Register Address Variable (Start address high bit)
  RS485Serial.write((byte)0x34); // Register Address Variable (Start address low bit)
  RS485Serial.write((byte)0x00); // Register Quantity (High Bit)
  RS485Serial.write((byte)0x02); // Register Quantity (Low Bit)
  RS485Serial.write((byte)0x90); // CRC check code (CRC code Low bit)
  RS485Serial.write((byte)0x05); // CRC check code (CRC code High bit)
}
```

and I need to read only the 4th and 5th frame of the packet. I am doing it the following way:

```c
RS485Serial.listen();            
  if (RS485Serial.available() > 0)  
   {

    if(RS485Serial.read() == 0x01)
    {
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {

   byte discard = RS485Serial.read();

   }
    byteReceived = RS485Serial.read(); // 4th frame
    byteReceived2 = RS485Serial.read(); // 5th frame
```

which is working fine. I wanted to know if there is a method to discard the packets without loop?

As in I have changed the `sendkwh()` as below:

```c
byte SendKWh[] = { 0x01, 0x03, 0x40, 0x34, 0x00, 0x02, 0x90, 0x05 };
RS485Serial.write(SendKWh, sizeof(SendKWh));
```

But don't know how to proceed with tapping the 4th and the 5th frame. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: What are the significance of the other bytes in the packet?

Comment: But the 4th and 5th frame actually needs to be sent to a server later in the code

Comment: If there was no significance they wouldn't exist. What do they all mean? As in - is there a packet header? A checksum? A packet length? What?

Comment: In a nutshell: your current reading methodology is seriously flawed and you're lucky it works at all.

Comment: Ok, sorry I didn't get your question at first. The other bytes have significance, as in Meter Address, Function Code, CRC code , etc

Comment: Can you suggest me how to improve it, or a reading that I may go through. Request your help on this!

Comment: That much is obvious. But you still haven't answered me. For me to help you I need to know **precisely what the meaning of each individual byte is within the packet**. Not just an "oh, it's such and such and such and such", but a list of "The first byte is... The second byte is... The third byte is..." etc, including how they are calculated (in the case of a CRC) or statically defined.

Comment: I am updating the question @Majenko

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your reading methodology is flawed from the start and you need to completely change how you do things.  First off, you wait until there is *at least* one byte in the incoming buffer, then if that byte is `0x01` you then try and read 5 more bytes - even if there is only (say) 2 bytes in the buffer.

Instead you need to set up a *sliding window* for receiving the data. A sliding window is basically an array that is the same size as the data you are receiving, and as bytes become available they work their way down from the "top" to the "bottom" of the array. When the contents of the array match a certain pattern you know it is a "good" packet and you can use the data form it.

For example, you may have something like:

```c
uint8_t window[8];

void loop() {
    if (RS485Serial.available()) {
        uint8_t b = RS485Serial.read();
        // Slide the contents of the array down
        for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            window[i] = window[i+1];
        }
        // Insert at the top
        window[7] = b;

        // If the array starts with 0x01,0x03,0x40,0x34...
        if ((window[0] == 0x01) && (window[1] == 0x03) &&
            (window[2] == 0x40) && (window[3] == 0x34)) {
            // Do something with window[4] and window[5]
        }
    }
}
```

You could also add checking the CRC to that by comparing the calculated CRC for the incoming packet (however that is done in this protocol) with the last two bytes of the array.

Comment: Just one quick question, What is the need to slide the contents of the array down ?

Comment: To make room for the new incoming byte. Yes, you could wrap around instead, using a circular buffer, but that gets more complicated to both code and understand. Think of the data as socks on a washing line. You are only interested in the 8 socks that begin with the sequence red, blue, green, yellow. The "window" is the gap between your hands held out in front of you (fingers up, palms away from you, thumb tips touching). You move the "window" (slide it) along the socks until you see just 8 starting with the right sequence.

Comment: If I give the condition as `(window[0] == 0x01) && (window[1] == 0x03) &&
 (window[2] == 0x40) && (window[3] == 0x34)` to `(window[0] == 0x01) && (window[7] == 0x05)` to confirm the window is covering the complete frame, then will I go wrong?

Comment: Yes, because `window[6]` and `window[7]` are the CRC and will change from packet to packet. You should, as I say in the last line of my answer, calculate the CRC and compare *that* to windows 6 and 7.